# Best distro for iMac 2008

Tags: mac

I have a 2008 iMac, 3ghz with 24" display. I'm able to install 19.04 Desktop AMD64 distribution using the safe graphics feature, but once I reboot after the install, I'm left with a black display. My guess is, based on some reading that it is a video card driver issue. I added, what I thought to be the current driver to the lib/firmware directory, but suspect I must need to edit a configuration file or initiate a setup or probe of the hardware to take advantage of the driver, as the results are unchanged.

Is this the right direction to go, if so, can someone point me to the correct step by step process? Or is it a better idea with this device, to use a different image file, if so any recommendation to a better option would be greatly appreciate? Best Regards...

Answer (score 0):

Given the age of the machine I'd suggest starting with a lighter distribution such as Lubuntu! Go with the [LTS version (18.04)](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/18.04.2/release/) and see how it goes!

I'd comment, but don't have privileges to do so yet, but you didn't mention what chipset you are running...

To probe hardware open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and type `sudo lshw`.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I'm going to give that a shot.